# Maps Won't Render - Using Rstudio, Plotly 4.9.0, Mapbox, geoJSON File

Tags: rstudio, plotly, mapbox, geojson

I am fairly new to plotting maps using Plotly in Rstudio. I've read that Mapbox can be used to create more complex maps. I wrote a few lines of simiple code to work with a geoJSON file, but my map won't render. The map renders with the plot_geo(), so I don't think it's an issue with the data. I also have an access token and verified thru a Mapbox test link that it is working. I have the correct version of plotly (4.9.0). I've called all the correct packages as far as I am aware. I thought I saw an example of where a Mapbox map can be rendered in Rstudio. Can you help me render my map?

Thanks so much!

Verified Mapbox public key is working
Checked Plotly version
Tried various ways of identifying Mapbox token key in .Renviron and Sys.setenv
Verified that there is no mapbox package to load
Updated R to 3.6.1
Updated R studio to 1.2.1335

## Current .Renviron entry

MAPBOX_TOKEN='pk.XXX'

## Render simple map using mapbox

library(plotly)
library(sf)
test<-st_read("D:/SPB/Zoning_Generalized.geojson", quiet=FALSE, , geometry_column="SHAPE_Area")
Sys.setenv('MAPBOX_TOKEN')
plot_mapbox(test)

Error #1

> Sys.getenv('MAPBOX_TOKEN')
> [1] ""

Error #2

> Error: No mapbox access token found. Obtain a token here
> https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-api-access-token/
> Once you have a token, assign it to an environment variable
> named 'MAPBOX_TOKEN', for example,
> Sys.setenv('MAPBOX_TOKEN' = 'secret token')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your views. The answer was simple. The .Renviron file entry looks like:

## note that there are no quotation marks

MAPBOX_KEY=pk.XXX

After saving the file, I had to restart RStudio. Then I added the line below which resulted in the entry below the line of code:

Sys.getenv("MAPBOX_TOKEN")
[1] "pk.XXX"